# Sort IP addresses with tuple python

Tags: python

I am trying to right some code that will take the output of a show command from a Cisco IOS device (redirected VIA tftp) and sort it based on IP address.  Ultimately I would take the CAM (mac-address table) and append this to it.

The output of the device looks like this:

```
Internet  172.17.150.198         77   000e.b6a9.e36d  ARPA   Vlan731/n
Internet  161.16.150.202         77   a0ec.f996.94d0  ARPA   Vlan777/n
Internet  161.16.152.199          2   0016.3e7c.8a25  ARPA   Vlan152/n
Internet  172.17.150.197         77   000e.b687.ee67  ARPA   Vlan731/n
Internet  161.16.150.201         77   0cf5.a4e4.d37b  ARPA   Vlan777/n
Internet  161.16.154.196          0   0050.56b3.0ac9  ARPA   Vlan154/n
Internet  161.16.152.198          1   0050.56b3.179d  ARPA   Vlan152/n
```

Code:

```
# Format and parse show interface status
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('Internet'):
    continue
b = line.split(); c = (b[-3] + b[-1]); b = b[1]
    ips.append(b)
# Sort IP
for i in range(len(ips)):
    ips[i] = "%3s.%3s.%3s.%3s" % tuple(ips[i].split("."))
ips.sort()
for i in range(len(ips)):
    ips[i] = ips[i].replace(" ", "")
for ip in ips:
print ip (would also like 'c')
```

This basically sorts everything by ip address (instead of the default sort that does not play nice with IP addresses).  What I really would like to do is split, and slice ips column 1, -3, and -1 and show that pair and a single line. IE:

```
161.16.150.201 0cf5.a4e4.d37b Vlan777/n
161.16.150.202 a0ec.f996.94d0 Vlan777/n
161.16.152.199 0016.3e7c.8a25 Vlan152/n
161.16.154.196 0050.56b3.0ac9 Vlan154/n
172.17.150.197 000e.b687.ee67 Vlan731/n
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your source you call `fhand`:

```
source = '''
Internet  172.17.150.198         77   000e.b6a9.e36d  ARPA   Vlan731/n
Internet  161.16.150.202         77   a0ec.f996.94d0  ARPA   Vlan777/n
Internet  161.16.152.199          2   0016.3e7c.8a25  ARPA   Vlan152/n
Internet  172.17.150.197         77   000e.b687.ee67  ARPA   Vlan731/n
Internet  161.16.150.201         77   0cf5.a4e4.d37b  ARPA   Vlan777/n
Internet  161.16.154.196          0   0050.56b3.0ac9  ARPA   Vlan154/n
Internet  161.16.152.198          1   0050.56b3.179d  ARPA   Vlan152/n'''

fhand = source.splitlines()
```

Then this code will sort on the IP address and will print every other column:

```
def ip_sort(key):
    """
    Assumes IP address is first element
    Splits the IP address and orders result numerically.
    """
    return [int(x) for x in key[0].split('.')]

keep = (line for line in fhand if line.startswith('Internet'))
keep = (tuple(line.split()[1::2]) for line in keep)
keep = sorted(keep, key=ip_sort)

for info in keep:
    print '%-15s %s %s' % info
```

Here is the output:

```
161.16.150.201  0cf5.a4e4.d37b Vlan777/n
161.16.150.202  a0ec.f996.94d0 Vlan777/n
161.16.152.198  0050.56b3.179d Vlan152/n
161.16.152.199  0016.3e7c.8a25 Vlan152/n
161.16.154.196  0050.56b3.0ac9 Vlan154/n
172.17.150.197  000e.b687.ee67 Vlan731/n
172.17.150.198  000e.b6a9.e36d Vlan731/n
```